# Как создать вложенный цикл

Tags: c#, mvc, foreach, for

Добры день, имею такой код:

```
foreach (var a in _ForumManager.GetChildSubForum(forum))
{
    <p style="margin-left:10px">@a.Name</p>

    foreach (var a1 in _ForumManager.GetChildSubForum(a))
    {
        <p style="margin-left:20px">@a1.Name</p>

        foreach (var a2 in _ForumManager.GetChildSubForum(a1))
        {
            <p style="margin-left:30px">@a2.Name</p>

            foreach (var a3 in _ForumManager.GetChildSubForum(a2))
            {
                <p style="margin-left:40px">@a3.Name</p>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В представлении. Он должен выводить древовидный список подфорумов. И он это делает, но предполагается что их глубина может быть бесконечна, а данный код выводит только подфорумы глубиной в 4. Как этот код можно заменить на что-то с while()? Я пытался, и даже почти получилось, но он выводит некоректно, ведь каждый форум может иметь два или более подфорума, поэтому я и использую foreach()

Comment: Вам нужна рефлексия. Некий метод, который будет вызывать сам себя и выполнять с переданными в него данными нужные действия до тех пор, пока не закончатся Child объекты.

Comment: Делаете UserControl, который выводит текущий форум как надо, а также все его подфорумы, причем подфорумы выводит с помощью самого себя - вложенного UserControl